# Determining the phase response of a PRBS 7 signal in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fft

I have taken a 32Gbps NRZ signal measurement using a real time oscilloscope. I have the time and values in 2 different columns (time domain data). I have imported the 2 values to two different arrays in Matlab (`NRZ_time`, `NRZ_values`).

Now, I want to compute the FFT of the signal. I know it can be done like this.

```
NRZ_fft = fft(NRZ_values);
```

Then, I want to plot the magnitude and phase response which I am doing with

```
figure;
plot(abs(NRZ_fft));
figure;
plot(angle(NRZ_fft));
```

I am sure the magnitude response is correct but the phase response is wrong according to me. Can someone confirm, I am doing it right or not?

Also I want to find the sampling frequency from this data. There are 65521 samples. The first value in the time column is `-0.0000000166801500` and the last value is `0.0000000345073500`. So, the length of the signal is:

```
0.0000000345073500 - (-0.0000000166801500) = 5.1187e-008.
```

How do I calculate the sampling frequency from this data?

Comment: (1) You are getting the phase right. (2) You can't simply take the last and first elements of your signal and subtract them.  The sampling frequency is defined as **how many samples obtained per second**.  Subtracting two time values from your vector doesn't give you this quantity.  It is also impossible to determine the sampling frequency from the frequency response as the magnitude & phase are being plot with respect to normalized frequency (`[0,1)`).   Unfortunately, you'll need to know the sampling frequency of the data *a priori*. Minor note: Why is the beginning time index **negative**?

Comment: These values are taken from a real time oscilloscope. I had not changed any settings in the oscilloscope. I have a 4:1 MUX. I sent four 8 Gbps signals to the MUX and the output is a 32 Gbps signal. The input pattern is a PRBS7 signal. I measured this in the real time oscilloscope and saved the data values in a csv which I am now processing in Matlab.I am not usre why the first time value is a negative value.

Comment: As @rayryeng mentioned, the sampling frequency is the number of samples per seconds, so if 65521 samples are obtained in 5.1187e-8 seconds, the sampling frequency should be (65521-1)/5.1187e-8 ~ 1280GHz. That is if those time values are in seconds (and assuming uniform sampling).

Comment: @SleuthEye - Nice.  I missed reading the last part of the post.  Oops!  nkp - Are the samples obtained using uniform sampling?  If it is, then what SleuthEye calculated is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies SleuthEye and rayryeng. I assume it is uniform sampling since I have taken it from a real time oscilloscope. But I will confirm this by reading some material. Thanks again for solving my problem.